# GAE TimeEntry application Date serialization exception

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying Google app engines sample application [TimeEntry](http://code.google.com/p/gae-timecard/source/browse/?r=7#svn/TimeEntry%253Fstate%253Dclosed). when I try to run it, it shows the exception i've added at the end. I've looked and tried solutions provided in other threads and forums but still i couldn't fix it.I am running it on Eclipse, app engine sdk 1.7.0 and gwt  2.4.0. your help will be greatly appreciable.. thanks!!
here is the output error message

```
Aug 28, 2012 6:39:51 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Date' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = Tue Aug 07 22:00:00 UTC 2012
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:619)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:709)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:748)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:621)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Collection_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Vector_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(Vector_CustomFieldSerializer.java:39)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Vector_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(Vector_CustomFieldSerializer.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Vector_CustomFieldSerializer.serializeInstance(Vector_CustomFieldSerializer.java:28)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:740)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:621)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:539)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:474)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:571)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:370)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 1):

try running your date moving to client run trough this:

```
**import java.util.Date;**

public class ConvertDate {
    public static Date g(Date date) {
        if (date != null) {
            long timeStamp = date.getTime();
            return new Date(timeStamp);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```